# remove the words from string using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, split

I have the date string in the following way :

### input:

```
$date = "Thu Jul 12 2012 11:03:36 GMT 0";
```

How do i remove the last words, starting from 'GMT' using regex.

### output:

```
Thu Jul 12 2012 11:03:36
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$newdate = preg_replace("/GMT(.*)/i", "", $date)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = preg_replace('~\s+GMT.*$~', '', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$newdate = preg_replace('\sGMT(.*)', '', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime object

```
$i = 'Thu Jul 12 2012 11:03:36 GMT 0';
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s * *', $i);
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); # or whatever you need
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would to to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and use a `pattern` ([30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)).

```
<?php
    $string = 'Thu Jul 12 2012 11:03:36 GMT 0';
    $pattern = '/GMT [0-9]*/';
    $replacement = ' ';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Thu Jul 12 2012 11:03:36
```

or [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) `$string = explode('GMT', $string);`